# restructure json based on parent

Tags: javascript, json, data-structures

I am studying the use of `reduce` in javascript, and I am trying to restructure an Array of Objects in a generic way - need to be dynamic.

[flowchart](https://www.draw.io/?lightbox=1&target=blank&highlight=0000ff&edit=_blank&layers=1&nav=1&title=desafio-tank#R7Vpbd9o4EP41nNM%2BpMe2bAceuZiG3QRSIE14FFjY3hjkyiLA%2FvqVbAljC8ItENqzL0Ea3We%2Bb2YkpwTqk8V3AiP%2FAbsoLBmauyiBRskwbMNmf7lgmQrKmhB4JHBTkZYJesG%2FKBXqUjoLXBQLWSqiGIc0iPLCEZ5O0YjmZJAQPM93G%2BPQzQki6CFF0BvBUJU%2BBy71xSmM20x%2BhwLPlyvrdiVtmUDZWZwk9qGL52si4JRAnWBM09JkUUch153Uy3Nr%2BRzev9rf%2F%2FoR%2F4JPtb%2F77Z836WTNQ4asjkDQlB49tXbfHbQbTeun1%2B2O7dcBRTV8Y4B07jcYzoTCBuK0dClViFymUVHFhPrYw1MYOpm0RvBs6iK%2BkMZqWZ97jCMm1JnwH0TpUsADzihmIp9OQtE6xlMqGnVT1sWS4vh8FwWT7tCH6BfjGRmhd5SQGZORAOEJomTJxhEUQhq85ReFAo7eqt9q6CMO2HYMTTAH2AJigjg6MPJTUEg8RMWozHBVQuByrVvEO8TvrGNUNq7TPK4%2FK6Q7kLU1nWSiBFsH4AzYCs7a14czUGOAIssXPv83S1YHYrmk0ljkaktRuwhEmedMIPOens2zYNnQK0wf66gxrP3Q%2FFEA0hT8NDpOj0n6dw77W3%2Fqdp12n5Ueq6LQ7HYekvYW79ZiQ2w4YSipTYdxlJhMc15aPd611V5NVK3Xnx6e7qv9TrcEmgpEiY8nwxk7cm3uBxT1IpiYbc5C5wagrQGrCDxxHEQoWhwBGdXCchZpF2GniqjOs9inA2FKfy3ulbXtmMjZ8lDDGeZ1MP9YZn9qZNK3GPtUOsshAiSWbV2UzLr%2BPps5Wf9McuadqKlZG9hpXJCdQFO0%2BD8Xtziy2z1jcJpfnUDa0%2FztrcKtaqMhSdXvFGhkaN1Op69SKWfia6WTXXRjFZVO8va2Tif7bMFOdWy%2FE7%2FQIqAvcg5WHmRTsFo2iFeugpN6eU9OnumKp9s5AOrgsmG0vAFtdsj0UHODtxzq7F8z%2FkxRYwykNzAMvGkJVFmPEI35edJ0mJvuJk5sydt0M1pkI1nJE79h%2BttMFslL4whONy580Nzn3%2F3WfY5wiEk6A%2FGGX1iI5gsYzEBaofz1sJW%2FEOTOGJgz9aV7OOO%2BTlfXV7mvIZGiZhI0nGr9jseUvvOw40SbcaJ0LjjJ2IcRL8YU8WATIRIwtiAiRI9ZfWdwChZIPkvu%2BdL08ZFKPrMJPyGzrvU4Je9t63EKmOdK%2B4yriFOfm89Ze8YOcOol7LSUwtqSz61dlZKs7rEqnkB%2Bx1QO2GY%2Bkmob3i0um8pVFL23nZe%2B6hBTH1gkTxgGUYx2KxzGUfrVI%2FFTn%2BWf9EreQdkVU1G%2FBVTtW%2BBM2gdqIv3nat%2By8vcYXbO%2BqQ8Dl9W%2Feou8hgBx7pggA%2B7OmHDyw9xp1lHfVOtdp9p3VmFh9QqevJ590BX%2F4l7JKitfHVS%2FpBsbnrPlS8DHq169c41no9eAwSXEzOUUtcxz8ILPSRPyxoipJklgueKCEQyromESuG5KH8TyczhMpuI2El8C2bxWrWQ1%2BFyMMfH23PZchjGL%2BaypK2Ypm6pVjiAEq2Zf2NOLc%2FZvCsD5Dw%3D%3D) - i get totaly lost

I started with this through.

*Every ID becomes a Key.*
*Every PARENT identifies which Key it belongs to.*

#### i have this:

```js
const in = [
  {
    "id": "Ball",
    "parent": "Futebol"
  },
  {
    "id": "Nike",
    "parent": "Ball"
  },
  {
    "id": "Volley",
    "parent": null
  }
]
```

#### i want this

```js
out = {
    "Futebol": {
        "Ball": {
            "Nike": {}
        }
    },
    "Volley": {}
}
```

#### i try it - and i had miserably failed.

```js
const tree = require('./mock10.json')

// Every ID becomes a Key.
// Every PARENT identifies which Key it belongs to.
const parsedTree = {}
tree.reduce((acc, item) => {
    if (parsedTree.hasOwnProperty(item.parent)){
        if (parsedTree[`${item.parent}`].length > 0) {
            parsedTree[`${item.parent}`][`${item.id}`] = {}
        } else {
            parsedTree[`${item.parent}`] = { [`${item.id}`]: {} }
        }
    } else {
        // i get lost in logic
    }
}, parsedTree)

console.log(parsedTree)
```

Comment: What is the limit on the number of elements nesting?

Comment: I would not like to think of a limit. to study this i created 3 mocks: one of 10 objects, another of 50 and 1000.

Comment: it makes things even more complicated if there are an infinity of levels ...

Answer (score 0):

Got a working code for you, feel free to ask me about the implementation

Hope it helps :)

```js
const arrSample = [
  {
    "id": "Ball",
    "parent": "Futebol"
  },
  {
    "id": "Nike",
    "parent": "Ball"
  },
  {
    "id": "Volley",
    "parent": null
  }
]

const buildTree = (arr) => {
  return arr.reduce(([tree, treeMap], { id, parent }) => {
    const val = {}
    treeMap.set(id, val)

    if (!parent) {
      tree[id] = val
      return [tree, treeMap]
    }

    if (!treeMap.has(parent)) {
      const parentVal = { [id]: val }
      treeMap.set(parent, parentVal)
      tree[parent] = parentVal
      return [tree, treeMap]
    }

    const newParentValue = treeMap.get(parent)
    newParentValue[id] = val
    treeMap.set(parent, newParentValue)
    return [tree, treeMap]
  }, [{}, new Map()])
}

const [result] = buildTree(arrSample)

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, 0, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce` method for this and store each id on the first level of the object. This solution will work if the objects in the array are in the correct order as in the tree structure.

```js
const data = [{"id":"Futebol","parent":null},{"id":"Ball","parent":"Futebol"},{"id":"Nike","parent":"Ball"},{"id":"Volley","parent":null}]

const result = data.reduce((r, { id, parent }) => {
  if (!parent) {
    r[id] = {}
    r.tree[id] = r[id]
  } else if (r[parent]) {
    r[parent][id] = {}
    r[id] = r[parent][id]
  }

  return r
}, {tree: {}}).tree

console.log(result)
```

Comment: `{"id":"Futebol","parent":null}` doesn't exist in the PO question, but as you say : "This solution will work if the objects in the array are in the correct order as in the tree structure."  and if there is only **3 levels max**

Answer (score 0):

If `reduce` solution is just an option, you can try this way:

```js
var input = [
  {
    "id": "Ball",
    "parent": "Futebol"
  },
  {
    "id": "Nike",
    "parent": "Ball"
  },
  {
    "id": "Volley",
    "parent": null
  }
];

var output = {};

input.forEach(item => {
  var temp = input.find(x => x.id === item.parent);
  if (temp) {
    temp[item.id] = {};
  }
});

input = input.filter(item => !input.find(x => x.hasOwnProperty(item.id)));

input.forEach(item => {
  if (!item.parent) {
    output[item.id] = {};
  } else {
    for (var [id, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
      if (typeof value === 'object') {
        output[item.parent] = { [item.id]: { id: {} } };
      }
    }
  }
})

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried many things, but none works if we use an Array.prototype.reduce

As there are missing parents, and the elements are out of order, plus the fact that there can be an infinity of levels, I really do not believe that this question can be resolved with a simple reduce

This code should work whatever the cases :
- if all parents are not declared
- if there are infinitely many levels
- if they are in disorder

```js
const origin = 
      [ { id: 'Ball',    parent: 'Futebol' } 
      , { id: 'Nike',    parent: 'Ball'    } 
      , { id: 'Volley',  parent: null      } 
      , { id: 'lastOne', parent: 'level4'  }  // added
      , { id: 'level4',  parent: 'Nike'    }  // added
      , { id: 'bis',     parent: 'Nike'    }  // added
      ];

const Result  = {}  // guess who ?
  ,   Parents = []  // tempory array to keep parents elements address by key names
  ;
let nbTodo = origin.length // need this one to verify number of elements to track
  ;

// set all the first levels, add a todo flags
origin.forEach(({id,parent},i,ori)=>
  {
  ori[i].todo = true       // adding todo flag
  if (parent===null) 
    {
    Result[id] = {}        // new first level element
    ori[i].todo = false    // one less :)
    nbTodo--
    Parents.push(({ref:id,path:Result[id]}) )             // I know who you are!
    }
  else if (origin.filter(el=>el.id===parent).length===0) // if he has no parent...
    {
    Result[parent] = {}                                 // we create it one
    Parents.push({ref:parent,path:Result[parent]} )
    }
  })

// to put the children back in their parents' arms
while(nbTodo>0) // while there are still some
  {
  origin.forEach(({id,parent,todo},i,ori)=> // little by little we find them all
    {
    if(todo) // got one !
      {
      let pos = Parents.find(p=>p.ref===parent) // have parent already been placed?
      if(pos) 
        {
        ori[i].todo = false          // to be sure not to repeat yourself unnecessarily
        nbTodo--                     // one less :)
        pos.path[id] = {}            // and voila, parentage is done
        Parents.push(({ref:id,path:pos.path[id]}) ) // he can now take on the role of parent
        }
      }
    })
  }
for (let i=origin.length;i--;) { delete origin[i].todo }  // remove todo flags


console.log( JSON.stringify(Result, 0, 2) )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

I finaly made this one, based on this previous on, and done with a first step by a reduce...

to by pass the Array of Parents, I made a recursive function for searching each parent elements thru the levels of parsedTree result.

here is the code:

```js
const Tree = 
      [ { id: 'Ball',    parent: 'Futebol' } 
      , { id: 'Nike',    parent: 'Ball'    } 
      , { id: 'Volley',  parent: null      } 
      , { id: 'lastOne', parent: 'level4'  }  // added
      , { id: 'level4',  parent: 'Nike'    }  // added
      , { id: 'bis',     parent: 'Nike'    }  // added
      ];


const parsedTree =  Tree.reduce((parTree, {id,parent},i ) => {
  Tree[i].todo = false
  if (parent===null) 
    { parTree[id] = {} }
  else if (Tree.filter(el=>el.id===parent).length===0) // if he has no parent...
    { parTree[parent] = { [id]: {} } }
  else
    { Tree[i].todo = true }
  return parTree
}, {})

function parsedTreeSearch(id, part)  {
  let rep = null
  for(let kId in part) {
    if (kId===id)
      { rep = part[kId] }
    else if (Object.keys(part[kId]).length) 
      { rep = parsedTreeSearch(id, part[kId]) }
    if (rep) break
  }
  return rep
}

while (Boolean(Tree.find(t=>t.todo))) {
  Tree.forEach(({id,parent,todo},i)=>{ // little by little we find them all
    if (todo) {
      let Pelm = parsedTreeSearch(parent, parsedTree)
      if (Boolean(Pelm)) {
        Pelm[id] = {}
        Tree[i].todo = false
} } }) }

for (let i=Tree.length;i--;) { delete Tree[i].todo }  // remove todo flags


console.log( JSON.stringify( parsedTree ,0,2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```